# How to get image url in DataTable js from data object?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, datatables, asp.net-core-mvc

I have js DataTable to display list of items.
Each item has few properties and few images.
I create js DataTable to display all info.
Everything is working except the image.
Usually image is accessible by link:

```
@product.ProductImages.ImageUrl
```

My js DataTable code:

```
    function loadDataTable() {
        dataTable = $('#tblData').DataTable({
            "ajax": { url: '/admin/product/GetAll' },
            "columns": [
                { data: 'name', "width": "15%" },
                { data: 'category.name', "width": "10%" },
                {
                    data: 'imageUrl', "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        return '<img src="' data.product.ProductImages.FirstOrDefault().ImageUrl + '" "/>';
                    }, "width": "10%"
                },
                { data: 'description', "width": "30%" },
                { data: 'price', "width": "5%" },
    }
]
```

Image is not showing up in the data table.
I tried using

```
<img src="' + data.ProductImages.FirstOrDefault().ImageUrl + '"
```

or just

```
<img src="' + data + '">
```

But nothing works..
I do have code in item controller to display images, and at debugging step it does show up, that each item has N number of images.. I just want to show 1 image in the table..

What am I doing wrong ?
Thank you.

================================
Update:

I followed Mr. Farid example, and got Image: null.
I guess I am getting image source link incorrectly.

Here is my model :

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public List<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class ProductImage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

So usually I retrieve images with linkL

```
product.ProductImages.ImageUrl;
```

Controller code:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    List<Product> productList = unitOfWork.Product.GetAll(includeProperties: "Category,ProductImages").ToList();

    return View(productList);
}
```

My JS code:

```
function loadDataTable() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/admin/product/GetAll',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);

            dataTable = $('#tblData').DataTable({
                data: response,
                columns: [
                    { data: 'name', "width": "15%" },
                    { data: 'category.name', "width": "10%" },
                    {
                        data: 'imageUrl',
                        "render": function (data, type, row) {
                            return '<img src="' + data + '" alt="' + row.name; '" style="height="100%  width="100%; "/>';
                        }, "width": "10%"
                    },
                    { data: 'description', "width": "30%" },
                    { data: 'price', "width": "5%" },
                         ]
            });
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

This is what I get from browser, I am using microsoft edge.
productImages: null.

Web page look
[image: web page look]

Browser tools response
[image: tools response]

Few more details:

If I debug controller index method, it shows complete list of products, with pictures and links to them.

[image: List of products]

Product with list of images:
[image: Product with list of images]

link to one of images of the product:
[image: link to one of images of the product]

hopefully this helps..

I probably should access image link somehow differently, but I cant figure out how..

Thank you.

Comment: There is not enough info in the question to give an answer without guesswork.  One thing you can do to help is to show us the JSON response from your Ajax call (as formatted text) in the question, so we can see its structure and some representative data.

Comment: If `imageUrl` in `data: 'imageUrl'` returns a valid image URL (like the name suggests) from your Ajax call, then you should be able to build the HTML string you need using `return '<img src="' + data + '" />';`. That should build a valid HTML string for your image tag. You can inspect the HTML to see what actually gets rendered. You can test the image URL separately to see if it is valid. I am not sure what `data.product.ProductImages.FirstOrDefault().ImageUrl` is trying to do.

Comment: Inspect your code (F12 in your browser most of the times) and navigate to your image to see the faulty source.

Comment: says src=undefined.    I am new to this, and I tried different things, but cant figure out correct way how to get "json response from ajax call"..  I just get an error 404 in console when inspecting the table page in browser..

Comment: It sounds as if you may not be familiar with the tools available in your browser. The "network" tab of your browser tools (F12 to open the tools) is where you can see the JSON results of your `"ajax": { url: '/admin/product/GetAll' }` call. Find a good browser tools tutorial for whatever browser you are using - and start there. It may be difficult to help you here, without that basic info.

Answer (score 0):

> But nothing works.. I do have code in item controller to display
> images, and at debugging step it does show up, that each item has N
> number of images.. I just want to show 1 image in the table..
>
> What am I doing wrong ?

Based on your scenario and description, it seems your `data.product.ProductImages.FirstOrDefault().ImageUrl` query might have the problem. Make sure its returning the single and correct image url which you are binding to your `image src`

As you haven't shared this details, so I couldn't test that. Apart from that, I have investigated with the demo image url and rest of the code and its working as expected.

Here is the steps how I investigated your scenario:

Demo Model:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Demo Cotnroller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Product> Get()

{

    return new List<Product>
        {
            new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Product 1", ImageUrl = "https://ip.keycdn.com/example.jpg?width=70&quality=10" },
            new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Product 2", ImageUrl = "https://ip.keycdn.com/example.jpg?width=70&quality=10" },

        };
}
```

View:

```
<table id="productTable" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Image</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
@section scripts {
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.6/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {


            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'https://localhost:7163/products/Get',
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $('#productTable').DataTable({
                        data: response,
                        columns: [
                            { data: 'id' },
                            { data: 'name' },
                            {
                                data: 'imageUrl',
                                render: function (data, type, row) {
                                    return '<img src="' + data + '" alt="' + row.name + '" height="50">';
                                }
                            }

                        ]
                    });

                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I updated my original question, following your instructions.